# What's an idiomatic way to implement a red-black tree in Go?

Tags: go, binary-search-tree, dry, red-black-tree

I'm new to Go and have implemented a binary search tree. The tree can store any value (specifically, anything that implements `interface{}`).

I'd like to build upon this implementation to create a self-balancing red-black tree. In an object-oriented language, I'd define a subclass of `BinarySearchTree` that adds a `color` data member, then override the `Insert` method to perform a balancing operation.

**Question: How can I implement a binary search tree and red-black tree in Go without duplicating code?**

### Current Binary Search Tree Implementation

Here's my binary search tree implementation:

```
package trees

import (
    "github.com/modocache/cargo/comparators"
    "reflect"
)

type BinarySearchTree struct {
    Parent *BinarySearchTree
    Left   *BinarySearchTree
    Right  *BinarySearchTree
    Value  interface{}      // Can hold any value
    less   comparators.Less // A comparator function to determine whether
                            // an inserted value is placed left or right
}

func NewBinarySearchTree(value interface{}, less comparators.Less) *BinarySearchTree {
    return &BinarySearchTree{Value: value, less: less}
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) Insert(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if tree.less(value, tree.Value) {
        return tree.insertLeft(value)
    } else {
        return tree.insertRight(value)
    }
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) insertLeft(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if tree.Left == nil {
        tree.Left = &BinarySearchTree{Value: value, Parent: tree, less: tree.less}
        return tree.Left
    } else {
        return tree.Left.Insert(value)
    }
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) insertRight(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if tree.Right == nil {
        tree.Right = &BinarySearchTree{Value: value, Parent: tree, less: tree.less}
        return tree.Right
    } else {
        return tree.Right.Insert(value)
    }
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) Find(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if reflect.DeepEqual(value, tree.Value) {
        return tree
    } else if tree.less(value, tree.Value) {
        return tree.findLeft(value)
    } else {
        return tree.findRight(value)
    }
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) findLeft(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if tree.Left == nil {
        return nil
    } else {
        return tree.Left.Find(value)
    }
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) findRight(value interface{}) *BinarySearchTree {
    if tree.Right == nil {
        return nil
    } else {
        return tree.Right.Find(value)
    }
}
```

Here's an example of how this struct may be used:

```
tree := NewBinarySearchTree(100, func(value, treeValue interface{}) bool {
    return value.(int) < treeValue.(int)
})
tree.Insert(200)
tree.Insert(300)
tree.Insert(250)
tree.Insert(150)
tree.Insert(275)
tree.Find(250) // Returns tree.Right.Right.Left
```

### Desired (But Impossible) Red-Black Tree Implementation

I'd like to "extend" the `BinarySearchTree` `struct` like so:

```
type RedBlackTree struct {
    Parent *RedBlackTree     // These must be able to store
    Left   *RedBlackTree     // pointers to red-black trees
    Right  *RedBlackTree
    Value  interface{}
    less   comparators.Less
    color RedBlackTreeColor  // Each tree must maintain a color property
}
```

And then "override" the `.Insert()` method like so:

```
func (tree *RedBlackTree) Insert(value interface{}) *RedBlackTree {
    var inserted *RedBlackTree

    // Insertion logic is identical to BinarySearchTree
    if tree.less(value, tree.Value) {
        inserted = tree.insertLeft(value)
    } else {
        inserted tree.insertRight(value)
    }

    // .balance() is a private method on RedBlackTree that balances
    // the tree based on each node's color
    inserted.balance()

    // Returns a *RedBlackTree
    return inserted
}
```

I don't think this is idiomatic Go code, however.

- Since `BinarySearchTree` is defined with pointers to other `BinarySearchTree` structs, a `RedBlackTree` that "extends" `BinarySearchTree` still has pointers to `BinarySearchTree` objects.
- There's no way to "override" `.Insert()`. My only option is to define another method, such as `.BalancedInsert()`.

### Currently Trying

One idea I'm currently trying is to define an interface such as this one:

```
type BinarySearchable interface {
    Parent() *BinarySearchable
    SetParent(searchable *BinarySearchable)

    Left() *BinarySearchable
    SetLeft(searchable *BinarySearchable)

    Right() *BinarySearchable
    SetRight(searchable *BinarySearchable)

    Value() interface{}
    Less() comparators.Less
    Insert(searchable *BinarySearchable) *BinarySearchable
    Find(value interface{}) *BinarySearchable
}
```

The `BinarySearchTree` and `RedBlackTree` will then implement these interfaces. One problem is how to share the `.Insert()` logic, however. Perhaps define a private function that each struct will use?

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I came up with. I'd rather accept another answer, but this is the best so far.

### The `BinarySearchable` Interface

Both `BinarySearchTree` and `RedBlackTree` conform to this interface. The file also defines functions common to all binary-searchable structs, including `insert()`, `.find()`, `leftRotate()`, and so on.

In order to dynamically create objects of various types, the `insert()` function takes a `childConstructor` function parameter. This function is used by `BinarySearchTree` and `RedBlackTree` to create child trees of arbitrary types.

```
// binary_searchable.go

type BinarySearchable interface {
    Parent() BinarySearchable
    SetParent(searchable BinarySearchable)
    Left() BinarySearchable
    SetLeft(searchable BinarySearchable)
    Right() BinarySearchable
    SetRight(searchable BinarySearchable)
    Value() interface{}
    Insert(value interface{}) BinarySearchable
    Find(value interface{}) BinarySearchable
    Less() comparators.Less
}

type childConstructor func(parent BinarySearchable, value interface{}) BinarySearchable

func insert(searchable BinarySearchable, value interface{}, constructor childConstructor) BinarySearchable {
    if searchable.Less()(value, searchable.Value()) {
        if searchable.Left() == nil {
            // The constructor function is used to
            // create children of dynamic types
            searchable.SetLeft(constructor(searchable, value))
            return searchable.Left()
        } else {
            return searchable.Left().Insert(value)
        }
    } else {
        if searchable.Right() == nil {
            searchable.SetRight(constructor(searchable, value))
            return searchable.Right()
        } else {
            return searchable.Right().Insert(value)
        }
    }
}
```

### `BinarySearchTree`

This is the "base" struct that is embedded in other tree structs. It provides default implementations of the `BinarySearchable` interface methods, as well as the data attributes each tree will use to store their children.

```
// binary_search_tree.go

type BinarySearchTree struct {
    parent BinarySearchable
    left   BinarySearchable
    right  BinarySearchable
    value  interface{}
    less   comparators.Less
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) Parent() BinarySearchable {
    return tree.parent
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) SetParent(parent BinarySearchable) {
    tree.parent = parent
}

// ...setters and getters for left, right, value, less, etc.

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) Insert(value interface{}) BinarySearchable {
    // Pass `insert()` a constructor that creates a `*BinarySearchTree`
    constructor := func(parent BinarySearchable, value interface{}) BinarySearchable {
        return &BinarySearchTree{value: value, less: tree.less, parent: parent}
    }
    return insert(tree, value, constructor).(*BinarySearchTree)
}

func (tree *BinarySearchTree) Find(value interface{}) BinarySearchable {
    return find(tree, value)
}
```

### `RedBlackTree`

This embeds `BinarySearchTree` and passes a custom constructor to `insert()`. The balancing code is omitted for brevity; you can [see the whole file here](https://github.com/modocache/cargo/blob/721d22653c013e3a5b28fd37ffe25033b123085a/trees/red_black_tree.go#L39).

```
// red_black_tree.go

type RedBlackTree struct {
    *BinarySearchTree
    color RedBlackTreeColor
}

func NewRedBlackTree(value interface{}, less comparators.Less) *RedBlackTree {
    return &RedBlackTree{&BinarySearchTree{value: value, less: less}, Black}
}

func (tree *RedBlackTree) Insert(value interface{}) BinarySearchable {
    constructor := func(parent BinarySearchable, value interface{}) BinarySearchable {
        return &RedBlackTree{&BinarySearchTree{value: value, less: tree.less, parent: parent}, Red}
    }

    inserted := insert(tree, value, constructor).(*RedBlackTree)
    inserted.balance()
    return inserted
}

func (tree *RedBlackTree) balance() {
    // ...omitted for brevity
}
```

If anyone has a more idiomatic design, or suggestions to improve this design, please post an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use embedding for [`example`](http://play.golang.org/p/l0-iCjWjhW) :

```
type A struct{}

func (a *A) fn()  { fmt.Println("A.fn") }
func (a *A) fn1() { fmt.Println("A.fn1") }

type B struct{ *A }

func (a *B) fn() { fmt.Println("B.fn") }

func main() {
    b := &B{&A{}}
    b.fn()
    b.fn1()
}
```

This should override the BST's `Insert` but keep all the other functions:

```
type RedBlackTree struct {
    *BinarySearchTree
    color RedBlackTreeColor // This is the only new attribute
}

func (tree *RedBlackTree) Insert(value interface{}) *RedBlackTree {}
```

http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding

//edit

Rereading the question you will have to change the logic a little

```
type RedBlackTree struct {
    *BinarySearchTree
}
type rbtValue struct {
    value interface{}
    Color RedBlackTreeColor
}
func (tree *RedBlackTree) Insert(value interface{}) (inserted *RedBlackTree) {
    if tree.less(value, tree.Value) {
        inserted = tree.insertLeft(&rbt{value, Red})
    } else {
        inserted = tree.insertRight(&rbt{value, Black})
    }
    inserted.balance()
    return inserted
}
```

Then make a comparator that works on `tree.Value.(rbtValue).Value`

Comment: I don't think this works. I am aware of embedding in Go, but the problem is that `.insertLeft()` sets `tree.Left = NewBinarySearchTree()`. I need this to be `tree.Left = NewRedBlackTree()`, since each node in a red-black tree must maintain a color property. However, since `Left` is defined as a `*BinarySearchTree`, I cannot set it to an instance of `*RedBlackTree`.

My original post included a definition of `type RedBlackTree struct` that had pointers to `*BinarySearchTree`, which is incorrect. I updated my original post.

Comment: I realized that after the answer, check the edit, however your answer is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though, it helped get me in the right direction. By the way, I was wondering: you embed using a pointer, i.e.: `*BinarySearchTree`. Searching the interwebs I found an example which embeds without using a pointer, i.e.: `BinarySearchTree`. Is there a difference?

Comment: Well, I used the pointer to avoid copies really, a bad habit of using pointers unless it's a native type or a very simple struct.